# Elixir Ecto 2: Self-referencing many_to_many and Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc. How?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to create a self-referencing `many_to_many` relationship in Ecto 2. I followed [this](http://swanros.com/self-referencing-many-to-many-relationships-using-ecto/) blogpost and got it working so far. However trying to update the associations with `Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc` always leads to an error. And I don't understand why.

**This is the setup:**

First the migrations to create users and the association table for contacts (every user can have multiple contacts which are also users):

```
# priv/repo/migrations/create_users_table.ex
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsersTable do  
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :username, :string
    end

    create unique_index(:users, [:username])
  end
end  

# priv/repo/migrations/create_contacts_table.ex
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateContactsTable do  
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:contacts) do
      add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing), primary_key: true
      add :contact_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing), primary_key: true

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

**Now the models:**

```
defmodule MyApp.User do  
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  alias MyApp.Contact

  schema "users" do
    field :username, :string
    # Add the many-to-many association
    has_many :_contacts, MyApp.Contact
    has_many :contacts, through: [:_contacts, :contact]
    timestamps
  end

  # Omitting changesets
end   

defmodule MyApp.Contact do  
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  alias MyApp.User

  schema "contacts" do
    belongs_to :user, User
    belongs_to :contact, User
  end
end
```

This now works:

```
user = Repo.get!(User, 1) |> Repo.preload :contacts
user.contacts
```

Now I'm trying to parse a string of comma-separated IDs, fetch the users, turn them into changesets and attach them as contacts to another user

```
# Parse string and get list of ids
contact_ids = String.split("2, 3, 4", ",") |> Enum.map(&String.trim/1)

# Get contacts
contacts = Enum.map(contact_ids, fn(id) ->
  Repo.get! User, id
end)

# Turn them into changesets
contact_changesets = Enum.map(contacts, &Ecto.Changeset.change/1)

# Update the associations
result = user |> Ecto.Changeset.change
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:contacts, contact_changesets)
|> Repo.update
```

The error I'm getting is

```
** (ArgumentError) cannot put assoc `contacts`, assoc `contacts` not found. Make sure it is spelled correctly and properly pluralized (or singularized)
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:568: Ecto.Changeset.relation!/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:888: Ecto.Changeset.put_relation/5
```

But I can preload the association and I can also manually create associations. So I could loop over the contact_ids and do this:

```
result = user 
|> Ecto.Changeset.change 
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:contacts, [Contact.changeset(%Contact{}, %{user_id: user_id, contact_id: contact_id})])
|> Repo.insert
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just using [`many_to_many`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3)?

Comment: @JustinWood I can only quote the [blog post](http://swanros.com/self-referencing-many-to-many-relationships-using-ecto/): `A member of the Elixir community told me on Slack that this looks more like a one-to-many relationship, and that I should try to represent it that way in my app. [...] During actual testing in my Phoenix app, I noticed that the query that Ecto was generating with the former association type was the wrong one. Switching it from many_to_many to has_many as above, fixed the issue.`

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce the problem with my own associations. I have a feeling you might at some point be working with `%MyApp.Contact{}` instead of `%MyApp.User{}`? Can you check that and report back?

Something that I did notice (but would not produce this error): you are trying to put `MyApp.User` changesets into the `:contacts` association, which requires `MyApp.Contact` changesets.

You could try to use [`many_to_many`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3). You can be sure you get back `MyApp.User` with it, so there will be less edge cases like this. It was specifically made for these types of associations anyways.

**MyApp.User schema:**

```
schema "users" do
  field :username, :string

  many_to_many :contacts, MyApp.User, join_through: MyApp.Contact, join_keys: [user_id: :id, contact_id: id]
  timestamps
end
```

I added the `join_keys` option, because I think without it Ecto might get confused in this situation. I suggest you try with and without it.

With `many_to_many` you can insert `MyApp.User` changesets directly into the `:contacts` association as well, which seems to be what you want to do.